# gammu-smsd RunOnReceive on delivered

Tags: gammu

I would like to get information about `DeliveredStatus` update for sms. The problem is that implementing `RunOnReceive` directive does not include information about which SMS is this message for. It's containing only "Delivered" message without any detailed information.

Is it possible to include somehow message ID in `RunOnReceive` directive? Or is there any other way to get information about message delivery status changed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, but there is [a pull request to do that](https://github.com/gammu/gammu/pull/320).

Comment: Yep, that's my PR.